# how to pass values from one activity to other using bundle

Tags: android, bundle

i am having many activities like settings,game,home etc.i want to accept some values from user in settings page.when i click on the done button all these values have to b stored in variables.at the same time i am going back to home page.from there i am going to game class.in that i want to get the previously stored values from settings page.i know using bundle is better to do this task.but i dnt knw how to use that for more than 1 value.plz help me.given below is my code snippet

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                namevalue=name.getText().toString();
                overvalue=over.getText().toString();
                audiostatus=audio.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.this,home.class);
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                 bundle.putString( "namevalue",namevalue);        
                 intent.putExtras(bundle);   
                 startActivity(intent);                 
                }
            });
```

Comment: SharedPrefernces is best for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Intent` itself to pass data from One `Activity` to another.
Use `intent.putExtra("NAME", data);`
you could refer to this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277784/593709)

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to send multiple data from one activity to other

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                namevalue=name.getText().toString();
                overvalue=over.getText().toString();
                audiostatus=audio.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.this,home.class);
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                 bundle.putString( "namevalue",namevalue);  
                 bundle.putString("overvalue",overvaluse);
                 bundle.putInt("value",variablename);
                 intent.putExtras(bundle);   
                 startActivity(intent);                 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

PS: Why not use SharedPrefernces to share your settings data  anywhere within your application?

Answer (score 1):

bundle.putStringArray allows you to put multiple string values. Check for other put*Array.

Comment: You could've edited your previous answer instead of posting another answer.