# How can I return a String or Array from onComplete? - Android - Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm programming an app that needs to fetch data in the **Firestore** data base. I created a Recyclerview that shows the results, but when I populate it, the information never arrives. I think is because I change the value of **Cervezas** inside the **onCompleteListener**.

The method **cargarDatos()** is in the same activity that the method **organizarDatos()**.

Before the methods I set the public variable:

```
public String Cervezas = "no information";
```

This is the code that organizes and populates the Recyclerviev:

```
private void cargarDatos() {

    final String user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    if(user.isEmpty()){

        Intent start_intent = new Intent
                (HistorialActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
        start_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(start_intent);
        finish();

    }

    mBaseDatos.collection("usuarios").document(user).collection("Historial")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult()){

                        organizarDatos(doc,user);

                        Pedidos pedidos = new Pedidos(doc.getId(),
                                Cervezas,
                                doc.getString("Precio"));

                        Log.d(TAG, "2 " + Cervezas);

                        pedidosList.add(pedidos);

                    }

                    adaptador = new ListItemAdaptador
                            (HistorialActivity.this,pedidosList);
                    listItem.setAdapter(adaptador);

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(HistorialActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


}
```

And this is the code that fetches the data:

```
private String organizarDatos(DocumentSnapshot doc, String user) {

    String idDoc = doc.getId();

    DocumentReference refBarriles = mBaseDatos.collection("usuarios").document(user)
            .collection("Historial").document(idDoc).collection("Barriles")
            .document("barriles");

    refBarriles.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                if (document != null) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());

                    String barriles = "BARRILES" + "\n";
                    Cervezas = "";

                    String bock = String.valueOf(document.get("Bock"));
                    if (bock != null){

                        barriles += "Bock: " + bock + "\n";
                    }

                    String scotch = String.valueOf(document.get("Scotch Ale"));
                    if (bock != null){

                        barriles += "Sotch Ale: " + scotch + "\n";
                    }

                    if (barriles.length() > 8){

                        Cervezas += barriles;


                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "1 " + Cervezas);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No existe ese documento");
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get() fallo con la exepcion: ", task.getException());
            }

        }
    });


    return Cervezas;
}
```

The one problem is that it doesn't give me any errors, but either populates the Recyclerview with the information, because the **OnComplete** doesn't return the String.

I spent hours looking at this, and for what I've learned, the OnComplete only can return void, but there has to be a way to pass that variable!

What can I do? thak you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the selectedListItem's object to another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277662/how-to-pass-the-selectedlistitems-object-to-another-activity)

Comment: The method **cargarDatos()** is in the same activity that the method **organizarDatos()**, and both methods are called several times in the **onCreate** of the activity.